# Retrieve rows in which a column doesn't contain a value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table like below:

```
| ID |  userIDs  
---------------
|  1 | 4,3,5   
|  2 | 2,3
|  3 | 1,2,3
```

I want to retrieve all the rows in which userIDs doesn't contain 1.
I tried

```
SELECT * FROM tablename  WHERE 1 NOT IN (userIDs)
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Could you give datatypes for the columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * FROM tablename  
WHERE find_in_set(1, userIDs) = 0
```

#### But actually you should rather change your table design. Never store multiple values in a single column!

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. BTB, !find_in_set(1, userIDs) also worked the same way.